# How to make simple summary variable in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, summary

I am working on a project where we are analyzing the psychological dimensions of people's conversational openers from around the world. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzejQ.png) is a really simple version of what I am working with.

I want to create a simple summary variable of the mean dimension rating for each country. For example, **what macro, formula, or function would I need to create a variable for the average hostility of country A?**

In reality, I have hundreds of countries so it would have to be a macro saying: For each hostility rating of an opener from country X, add up those ratings and divide by the number of items from country X to create variable CountryX_AvgHostility.

Comment: you would use AVERAGEIF()/AVERAGEIFS().

Comment: And to find your initial country data set, you would copy the country column and remove all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If your output table were like this (on Sheet2 for example):

```
   A              B
Country     Avg. Hostility
   A             ###
   B             ###
   C             ###
```

The formula in B2 could be:

```
= sumproduct(Sheet1!$C:$C, --(Sheet1!$B:$B = Sheet2!$A2)) / countif(Sheet1!$B:$B, Sheet2!$A2)
```

This formula assumes:

- The table you posted as a picture above is in Sheet1.

  - In your original table, country is in column B.
  - In your original table, hostility is in column C.
- Result table is in Sheet2.

The same is also possible with sumif(), as a side note. Averageif(), as Scott mentioned above, may even be easier.

**Edit:** you should use Averageif() as Scott describes in the comments below, it will compute much faster.

To put it into the same format:

```
=averageif(Sheet1!$B:$B, Sheet2!$A2, Sheet1!$C:$C)
```

Comment: FWIW SUMPRODUCT() is an array formula and one should avoid full column references as the calculations are exponential.  AVERAGEIF() is not an array formula, so `=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"A",C:C)` is acceptable.

Comment: @ScottCraner You're right, and I guess `sumproduct / countif` is a relic now from times before AVERAGEIF... But thanks for pointing this out, I totally forgot about AVERAGEIF

Comment: If you want to pull the math apart use SUMIF() instead of SUMPRODUCT().  again it avoids the array formula. `SUMIF(B:B,"A",C:C)/COUNTIF(B:B,"A")`

Comment: Oh I see... Another question, is SUMIFS an array formula? I'm starting to doubt my heavy use of SUMPRODUCT (though I usually define a limited range)

Comment: No SUMIFS() is not an array formula.  I tend to overuse sumproduct also. Now I try any of the other SUMIF() or COUNTIF() to do it first, then move to SUMPRODUCT().